# Interpretation of kruskal wallis test results

Tags: p-value, spss, median, kruskal-wallis-test

Hello I have run a kruskal wallis test to compare the median between three groups as in this picture below:[image]

I know what median value and p value are but:

1. IQR is the spread of data but what is used for here in kruskal wallis test?
2. What is the meaning of h value or h test statistic?
3. What is df?

I'm a beginner to spss if someone could explain it to me these three questions in simple terms I would really appreciate it.

I searched online but I don't seem to understand well.

Thank you

Comment: Kruskal Wallis does not compare medians.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kruskal-Wallis test is a rank-based nonparametric test.
The null hypothesis is that $k$ (here $k=3)$ samples come
from populations of the same shape and the same center (usually interpreted as the median). The alternative hypothesis is
that not all $k$ populations have the same center.

The test statistic $H$ is based on the ranks of all of the
observations in the $k$ groups. The statistic $H$ is larger
to the extent that the $k$ groups do not have the same center.

For small samples, special
tables may be used to decide wither $H$ is large enough
to reject $H_0.$ For larger samples, a $H$ has approximately
a chi-squared distribution with $\nu = k-1$ degrees of freedom. Notice in your example that $k = 3, \nu = 2.$

I will use R to illustrate the use of the Kruskal-Wallis test for two fictitious datasets, one where
the groups share a common center $(H_0$ true)
and one where one group has its center significantly shifted from the others.

(1) Example with $k= 4$ groups, where $H_0$ is true:

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = rgamma(20, 3, 1/5)
x2 = rgamma(20, 3, 1/5)
x3 = rgamma(20, 3, 1/5)
x4 = rgamma(20, 3, 1/5)
x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4)
g = rep(1:4, each=20)
```

Boxplots of the four groups show moderately right skewed samples. The median of the common population distribution
$\mathsf{Gamma}(3, 1/5)$ has mean $\mu = 15$ and median
$\eta \approx 13.37.$ All four groups have sample medians
(at lines within boxes) that are about the same.

```
boxplot(x~g, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

```
qgamma(.5, 3, 1/5)
[1] 13.3703
```

The Kruskal-Wallis test had $H = 0.2135$2 and the P-value
of the test is $0.97 > 0.05,$ so the null hypothesis that
the groups have the same centers is not rejected.

```
kruskal.test(x~g)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  x by g
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 0.21352, df = 3, p-value = 0.9754
```

Here is a plot of the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 3).$ The observed value of $H$ is shown as a solid vertical line. The critical value $c = $ of this distribution is
$c = 7.815.$ which cuts 5% of the area from the upper tail
of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 3).$ Because $H < c,$ we do not
reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance.

```
qchisq(.95, 3)
[1] 7.814728
```

[image]

R code for figure:

```
curve(dchisq(x, 3), 0, 12, col="blue", lwd=2,
  ylab="Density", xlab="h", main="PDF of CHISQ(3)")
abline(h=0, col="green2")
abline(v=0, col="green2")
abline(v = 0.21352, lwd=2)
abline(v = 7.814728, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

(2) Example with $k= 5$ groups, where $H_0$ is false:
The last sample is shifted to the right relative to the
other four.

```
set.seed(517)
y1 = rgamma(20, 5, 1/5)
y2 = rgamma(20, 5, 1/5)
y3 = rgamma(20, 5, 1/5)
y4 = rgamma(20, 5, 1/5)
y5 = rgamma(20, 5, 1/5) + 15
y = c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)
g = rep(1:5, each=20)
```

For these data, the boxplot shows that the 5th sample is
shifted to the right.

```
boxplot(y~g, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

The Kruskal-Wallis test has test statistic $H =17.17,$
the critical value is $c = 9.49$ and the P-value is about 0.02 = 2% < 5%. We reject $H_0$ at the 5% level of significance because $H > c$ or because the P-value is below 5%.

```
kruskal.test(y~g)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  y by g
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 17.17, df = 4, p-value = 0.001791

qchisq(.95, 4)
[1] 9.487729
```

A plot of the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 4)$ with the observed value of $H$ and the critical value is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much